# Recursive directory traversal in perl

Tags: perl, file, recursion, traversal

I intend to recursively traverse a directory containing this piece of perl script.
The idea is to traverse all directories whose parent directory contains the perl script  and list all files path into a single array variable. Then return the list.

Here comes the error msg:

```
readdir() attempted on invalid dirhandle $DIR at xxx 
closedir() attempted on invalid dirhandle $DIR at xxx
```

Code is attached for reference, Thank you in advance.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
our @childfile = ();
sub recursive_dir{

    my $current_dir = $_[0]; # a parameter

    opendir(my $DIR,$current_dir) or die "Fail to open current directory,error: $!";
    while(my $contents = readdir($DIR)){
        next if ($contents =~ m/^\./); # filter out "." and ".."
        #if-else clause separate dirs from files 
        if(-d "$contents"){
            #print getcwd;
            #print $contents;
            #closedir($DIR);
            recursive_dir(getcwd."/$contents");
            print getcwd."/$contents";
        }
        else{
            if($contents =~ /(?<!\.pl)$/){
                push(@childfile,$contents);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($DIR);
    #print @childfile;
    return @childfile;
}

recursive_dir(getcwd);
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AFind).

Comment: I am not supposed to use a library.

Comment: @user3368737 Why not? Is this homework? File::Find is a core module, like toolic says, no need to install.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice File::Find is a core module. But the question is still open, for curiosity

Comment: As someone has said use 'File::Find', the file test operators like  '-f -d -s' and also don't forget 'stat' and 'lstat'

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us if this is homework? You are welcome to ask for help with assignments, but it changes the sort of answer you should be given.

You are relying on `getcwd` to give you the current directory that you are processing, yet you never change the current working directory so your program will loop endlessly and eventually run out of memory. You should simply use `$current_dir` instead.

I don't believe that those error messages can be produced by the program you show. Your code checks whether `opendir` has succeeded and the program dies unless `$DIR` is valid, so the subsequent `readdir` and `closedir` *must* be using a valid handle.

Some other points:

- Comments like `# a parameter` are ridiculous and only serve to clutter your code
- Upper-case letters are generally reserved for global identifiers like package names. And `$dir` is a poor name for a directory handle, as it could also mean the directory name or the directory path. Use `$dir_handle` or `$dh`
- It is crazy to use a negative look-behind just to check that a file name doesn't end with `.pl`. Just use `push @childfile, $contents unless $contents =~ /\.pl$/`
- You never use the return value from your subroutine, so it is wasteful of memory to return what could be an enormous array from every call. `@childfile` is accessible throughout the program so you can just access it directly from anywhere
- Don't put scalar variables inside double quotes. It simply forces the value to a string, which is probably unnecessary and may cause arcane bugs. Use just `-d $contents`
- You probably want to ignore symbolic links, as otherwise you could be looping endlessly. You should change `else { ... }` to `elsif (-f $contents) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not homework, just a script that help me to crunch some data. I am new to perl, a long way to go still.